# PHP: Textbox Separate Emails

Tags: php, email

If I have a textbox where a user can enter multiple emails, i.e.

```
test@test.com
test2@test2.com
email3@email3.com
```

How can I use PHP to separate each email into an array/object?

Is it possible to give the users the option to separate by ';' or ',' or a new line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give the user a delimiter character, you can use [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).  For instance, using `;`:

```
$emails = explode(';', $_GET['emails']);
```

You could use `,` or `\n` (new line) instead of `;` if you preferred.

If you wanted to divide the string based on *all* these characters, use [`preg_split`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php):

```
$emails = preg_split('/[;,\n]/', $_GET['emails']);
```

Example:

```
<?php

$emails = 'test@test.com;test2@test2.com
email3@email3.com,email4@email4.com';

$emails = preg_split('/[,;\n]/', $emails);

print_r($emails);
/*
Array
(
    [0] => test@test.com
    [1] => test2@test2.com
    [2] => email3@email3.com
    [3] => email4@email4.com
)
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Use explode() which returns an array of strings, each of which is a substring of string formed by splitting it on boundaries formed by the string delimiter.

```
array explode ( string $delimiter , string $string [, int $limit ] )
```

Example:

```
<?php
$str = 'one|two|three|four';

// positive limit
print_r(explode('|', $str, 2));

// negative limit (since PHP 5.1)
print_r(explode('|', $str, -1));
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => one
    [1] => two|three|four
)
Array
(
    [0] => one
    [1] => two
    [2] => three
)
```

***Update:***

If you want to split by an array of delimiters you would need to use [preg_split()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) with the appropriate regular expression.

Comment: What if | is not the only delimiter?  I.e. a new line, comma, semicolon?

Comment: Then you would need to use a more complex expression such as preg_match_all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a delimiter such as a space or a slash and then on the PHP side of things use the explode function php.net/explode to split it.