# Separating Multiple Email Addresses in PHP

Tags: php

Following this thread:

[PHP: Textbox Separate Emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011536/php-textbox-separate-emails)

I am attempting to separate multiple email addresses that are being entered into a textbox. My problem is that if I use the advice from above:

```
$emails = preg_split('/[;,\n]/', $_POST['email_receivers']);
```

It works great only if there is no space after the delimiter. How can I adjust this so that someone can separate email addresses by either just the delimiter or the delimiter plus a space.

eg.  (`email1@xyz.com;email2@xyz.com`) AND (`email1@xyz.com; email2@xyz.com`) should both work but currently only the first example works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd like to improve Michael Berkowski's answer by making the spaces optional:

```
$emails = preg_split('/\s*[;,\n]\s*/', $_POST['email_receivers']);
```

`\s+` requires one or more spaces. `\s*` makes them optional (zero or more)